# How to enable Javascript code with a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to enable a Javascript code only when I check a checkbox.

I want to insert a script so I can enable and disable the script by only checking or unchecking the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to run only when the check box is checked, just wrap that code in a function, then check if that checkbox is checked at the top of said function.  If it's not checked, `return` to stop the rest of the function from running.

```
function codeToRun() {

    var myCheckbox = document.getElementById("checkbox-id");

    if (!myCheckbox.checked) {
        return;
    }

    // Whatever code you want to be run
    doWhatYouWantToDoHere();
}
```

If the checkbox isn't checked, the function will `return` without running all the way through.  If it is checked, the function will run normally.